# Silverlight Spell Checker

Tags: .net, silverlight, spell-checking

I have a requirement to allow spell checking for some textboxes in a Silverlight application.

I'm looking for a server-side solution. By server-side I mean that the dictionary doesn't reside on the client.

I have Telerik RadControls for Silverlight, which has the RadSpellChecker and the RadRichTextBox which supports spell checking, but as far as I know have to include the 3mb+ dictionary in the XAP file and the size of the xap is a concern.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Telerik's RadSpellChecker, you are not limited to use only the built-in spellchecker and dictionaries, so your scenario is pretty plausible. There are several ways you can use the functionality of this control on the server. One approach would be to create a service, implementing the interface Telerik.Windows.Documents.Proofing.ISpellChecker, which contains a method that returns a list of words (suggestions). As far as I know, this would be the best way to handle the problem in your case. 
Another solution would be to download the dictionary asynchronously (which by the way is 900KB when zipped) after the application has loaded and after that enable spellchecking. 
The best you can do is to visit some of the Telerik forums or contact the Telerik support team, who I am sure, will provide you with the best solution they can think of.

Answer (score 0):

I know there are a number of vendors that provides webservice calls for spell checking, I've looked at a few but never went far enough to investigate the APIs. I believe most of them are standard wsdl type webservices. Have you googled it?
I find it interesting that the Telerik dictionary is so big, when cellphones first got spell checkers / predictive text you could fit most of the most common English words in to less than 1/2 a Mb, are you sure they don't have options around subsets of dictionaries etc

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to do the spell checking on client side utilizing Google API, checkout [SpellLight](https://spelllight.codeplex.com/) library for Silverlight. It requires elevated trust to work though to communicate with Google.